# Сan't automatically connect to RDS via the script?

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-ec2

I'm using script on ec2 user data, that connects to rds. But the script doesn`t work.

```
#! /bin/bash 
yum update -y
yum install -y httpd
service httpd start
usermod -a -G apache centos
chown -R centos:apache /var/www
yum install -y mysql php php-mysql
systemctl enable httpd.service
cd /var/www/html/
echo "[mysql]" > ~/.my.cnf
echo "user = myuser" >> ~/.my.cnf
echo "password = passworddata" >> ~/.my.cnf
chmod 600 ~/.my.cnf   
cd database/
mysql -h db_server_address < script.sql
systemctl restart httpd.service
```

/var/log/cloud-init-output.log
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'10.0.0.172' (using password: NO)

When I do it manually on the instance everything works fine.I understand that the script is not perfect, but what's the problem, why the script don`t take credentials from ~/.my.cnf?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27086639/user-data-scripts-is-not-running-on-my-custom-ami-but-working-in-standard-amazo) help?

Comment: @mustaccio - In my case it is standard Amazon linux.

Comment: 10.x.x.x IP addresses are local to a given network.  Are you coming from _your_ machine?  Or did you somehow connect into the _cloud_?

Comment: @RickJames - Im use terraform to create infrastr. in AWS.( I'm new on scripting, so have some problem.)